# Format Google Sheets cell as a currency number after value is returned by a custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I can't figure out how to currency format a cell where the value is loaded from a custom function. The value is a string (contains only numbers). If I will return a formatted string with currency sign I will not be able to make arithmetical actions with that cell.

I have tried to add the formatting action to onEdit function:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  activesheet.getRange("B3:Z3").setNumberFormat("$0,000.00");
}
```

But the values in rows B3:Z3 are still not formatted after edit.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that `activesheet` means anything at all? Look at the Apps Script documentation on `event objects` and see what parameters you have available. Also note that you could simply define a custom number format for that static range of cells in the actual spreadsheet menus, and have your custom function return a numeric value.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention activesheet is my getActiveSheet() object and there's no problem with that. I have tried to custom format by pressing Format -> Number -> Currency. It does format when there's a static data in that cell, but does not if data is loaded by =myFunc()

Comment: Cell formats do not require the value to be static. If they are not formatting the way you expect, then the data is not if the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might experience the same issue, I will post the solution that worked for me:

In my case my custom function myFunc() returned a string (even it contained numbers only). I thought it is eligible for formatting in that case and I was wrong.

The fix is to use [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or parseFloat() on the data that is being returned by myFunc(), so the data type will be a number.